# Detect when java program fails when being called from bash

Tags: java, bash

I have a very simple bash script which calls a java program. I need this bash script to write output to stdout if the java program runs successfully or fails.

```
#!/bin/bash
if java -jar java_program.jar arg1 ; then echo "run:yes"
    else echo "run:no"
fi
```

if my java program returns

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>           at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
>           at com.redacted.redacted.AdvancedEncryptionStandard.decrypt(AdvancedEncryptionStandard.java:48)
>           at com.redacted.redacted.App.getStuff(App.java:58)
>           at com.redacted.redacted.App.main(App.java:27)

My bash script will still return "run:yes". I'm assuming this is because as far as bash is concerned it called the script and it ran. Is there a way for me to decet if the java program actually runs successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you must use `System.exit(0)` from inside your java program to finish the execution and communicate to bash that everything was OK. Just return `1` instead `0` to communicate an error. The response will be stored at `$?` inside your bash environment to be used at `if`.

There's another answer on how to use the `$?` result on bash:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-to-conditionally-do-something-if-a-command-succeeded-or-failed

Answer (score 0):

Normally exiting the 'main' method (without explicit exit) will return '0' to the shell. Uncaught exceptions will return status of 1.

```
javac a
java a
xception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception
    at a.main(a.java:4)

echo $?
=> 1
```

Where a is just

```
class a {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello\n") ;
        throw new Exception() ;
    }
}
```

On surface, this is a case when the `main` just catch the exception, print it, and ignore the exception, therefore the calling process return 0

```
class a {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello\n") ;
        try {
          doSomething() ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace) ;
        } ;
    }
}
```

Few possible approaches: (1) rewrite the main to allow the exception to 'bubble up' and (2) write new main that will execute the old main, and check for success (3) capture stderr, and check for error messages (messy). Otherwise, you are out of luck